# Why did SpaceX retire Falcon 1?

Tags: spacex, rockets, falcon-9, design, falcon-1

Why did SpaceX retire Falcon 1? Wouldn't it have been more cost effective then Falcon 9 for lighter missions?

Comment: I wonder what happened to Falcon-2 through Falcon-8...

Comment: @Criggie Falcon 9 has 9 engines, versus Falcon 1's 1 engine.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

The Falcon 1 was less profitable to maintain, and it didn't have the customer base to support using it. A Falcon 1 launch cost around $10 million, of which about 10% was profit. They also considered a Falcon 1e design, which would carry slightly more to orbit, but only 1100 kg tops.

There were a few people who are known to have booked a Falcon 1 launch, namely DoD (TacSAT-1), MDA Corp, Swedish Space Corp, the US Air Force, and ORBCOMM. Most of these could be done with a Falcon 9, and many were given a huge discount to use the larger rocket.

Keep in mind that the Falcon 1 had a development cost of around \$100 million. At best it would make \$1 million profit per launch. Without considerable demand, it wasn't worth continuing to develop that rocket.

At the same time, NASA came knocking on SpaceX's door with a $400 million contract to build a ISS resupply mission. SpaceX was broke, and it would have been hard to justify continuing the development of Falcon 1 which would never see a huge return on it's money. In the end, they opted to pursue NASA's money, which pretty much required them to abandon the Falcon 1 design entirely.

The bottom line is, Falcon 1 wasn't profitable enough to continue with, and had to be abandoned, in order to make room for the more capable and profitable Falcon 9.

Comment: You mean to say the Falcon 1 was efficient for smaller payloads but the the market of smaller payloads itself is small and less profitable?

Comment: Yes, that sums it up quite well.

Comment: check this link out https://futurism.com/?p=119822

Answer (score 14):

Viewing SpaceX's history, I get the distinct impression that Falcon 1 was a development vehicle: it allowed SpaceX to test the Merlin engine, and it allowed them to demonstrate they were a viable business.

From early on in their history, SpaceX has been trying to lower launch cost through [reuse](http://www.spacex.com/falcon9). There were plans to recover the first stage of the Falcon 1 (via [parachute landings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Falcon_1)) but those plans were shelved.

My guess is that the extra hardware needed would reduce F1's payload by too much, or they realized refurbishing a booster after a parachute landing in water wasn't going to be cheap.

SpaceX said the market for Falcon 1-sized payloads was too small to pursue.

Instead, development effort was concentrated on Falcon 9, which has much larger margins for recovery.

> SpaceX believes rocket reusability is the key breakthrough needed to reduce the cost of access to space and enable people to live on other planets.

Running 2 programs in parallel (F1/F9) would have spread engineering resources, delaying the F9 program.